# Class transformer: Property that is an object with properties that is another class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class-transformer

```
class ClassA {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    sum(): number {
        return this.x + this.y;
    }
}

class ClassB {
    @Type(() => ClassA)
    z: {[key: string]: ClassA};
}

const b = plainToInstance(ClassB, plainObj);
const z = b.z[key];
const s = z.sum();
```

Error because b.z is not correctly transformed into key-value pair of ClassA, it doesn't have sum().

What is the correct way to do this?

```
plainObj = {z: {key1: {x: 1, y: 2}, key2: {x: 10, y: 20}}
```

Comment: Please provide `plainToInstance()` and `plainObj`. You surely did not instanciate a new A in `plainToInstance`

Comment: @IQbrod If z is ClassA[] not {[key: string]: ClassA}, it will work. Class-transformer does not require manually new a class instance.

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what's wrong without source code of plainToInstance ?

Comment: @IQbrod Class-transformer is a widely used library on github

Comment: Atleast give the value of ```plainObj``` so that people know what kind of object you are trying to validate. I guessed the value of ```plainObj``` and was thinking of using ```@Transform``` but could not come up with anything. Maybe your object will help.

Comment: @AmitKumar `plainObj = {z: {key1: {x: 1, y: 2}, key2: {x: 10, y: 20}}` could be used as an example. `@Transform` works as I'm currently using it, but it feels like an overkill. I mean why not just remove `@Type` and use `@Transform` for all type conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it working, the [docs](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) mention usages of `Map` but i couldn't get it working. Turns out you also need to set `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` in tsconfig.json.

you need to change your `ClassB`

```
class ClassB {
  @Type(() => ClassA)
  z: Map<string, ClassA>;
}
```

then it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `@transform()` directly on your custom property.

```
  @Transform(({ value, key, obj, type }) => ({ x: obj.b, y:obj.c }))
  customData?: CustomDto;
```

The cool thing is the `obj`, it's the current object, so you can use it to form the shape of your customData object as your wish.